# How can one simulate quantities of interest from the posterior density in MCMCglmm?

Tags: r, simulation, bayesian, mixed-models, r-zelig

I would like to simulate quantities of interest from a model estimated with `MCMCglmm` more or less the way `Zelig` package does. In `Zelig` you can set the values you want for the independent values and software calculates the result for the outcome variable (expected value, probability, etc). An example:

```
# Creating a dataset:
set.seed(666)
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100,20,20),z=rnorm(100,50,70))

# Loading Zelig
library(Zelig)

# Model
m1.zelig <- zelig(y~z, data=df, model="ls")
summary(m1.zelig)

# Simulating z = 10
s1 <- setx(m1.zelig, z = 10)
simulation <- sim(m1.zelig, x = s1)
summary(simulation)
```

As we can see, if z = 10 y is approximately 17.

```
# Same model with MCMCglmm
library(MCMCglmm)
m1.mcmc <- MCMCglmm(y~z, data=df, family = "gaussian", verbose = FALSE)
summary(m1.mcmc)
```

Is there any way to simulate z = 10 with the posterior distribution estimated by `MCMCglmm` and get the expected value of y? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate, but not as easily as in Zelig.  You have to know a little more about the structure of the model you're fitting and the way the parameters are stored in the `MCMCglmm` object.

Set up data and fit:

```
set.seed(666)
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100,20,20),z=rnorm(100,50,70))
library(MCMCglmm)
m1.mcmc <- MCMCglmm(y~z, data=df, family = "gaussian", verbose=FALSE)
```

The most common protocol in R for prediction and simulation is to set up a new data frame with the same structure as the original data:

```
predframe <- data.frame(z=10)
```

Construct the model matrix for the linear model:

```
X <- model.matrix(~z,data=predframe)
```

Now use the chains of coefficients stored in the `Sol` ("solution") component of the `MCMCglmm` object; for convenience, I've set this up as a matrix calculation.

```
predframe$y <- X %*% t(m1.mcmc$Sol)
```

If you want to simulate for more complicated models (linear or generalized linear mixed models) then you'll need to work a little harder (handle random effects and inverse-link functions appropriately) ...

Comment: Dear Ben, thank you very much for your quick reply. That's exactly what I wanted to do. Regarding simulation for more complex models, do you have any suggestion from where to start? Once again, thanks for the response.

Comment: I'd probably make sure I'd gone carefully through the `MCMCglmm` vignettes, which have a lot of information, and make sure you know the model structures: for example, you want something like `Z ~ model.matrix(~[random effects formula, with intercepts suppressed])`; then multiply `Z` by the `$Liab` component (latent effects).  You need to set `pl=TRUE` when running the model to get it to save the latent effects.

Comment: your suggestion works great. However, when I tried to include more predictors and run a Poisson model the results look very different from those I got in `Zelig`. I included other predictors in the `predframe`, repeated the same model matrix you described above (plus the additional variables) and multiplied by the `$Sol' component of a (single level) Poisson model estimated with `MCMCglmm'. Finally, to obtain the quantity of interest, I typed `exp(mean(predframe$y))`. Is there anything else I might be missing? Thanks again!

Comment: the only thing that looks funny is taking the mean of the linear predictor (`predframe$y`) before exponentiating -- why not just `exp(predframe$y)` ?  Otherwise, a reproducible example would be best.  (Maybe you should ask a new question rather than extending this one -- I'm not sure.)