# How to simulate quantities of interest using arm or rstanarm packages in R?

Tags: r, bayesian, stan, r-zelig

I would like to know how to simulate quantities of interest out of a regression model estimated using either the `arm` or the `rstanarm` packages in R. I am a newbie in Bayesian methods and R and have been using the `Zelig` package for some time. I asked a similar question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057548/how-can-one-simulate-quantities-of-interest-from-the-posterior-density-in-mcmcgl), but I would like to know if it is possible to simulate those quantities using the posterior distribution estimated by those packages.

In `Zelig` you can set the values you want for the independent values and it calculates the results for the outcome variable (expected value, probability, etc). An example:

```
# Creating a dataset:
set.seed(10)
x <- rnorm(100,20,10)
z <- rnorm(100,10,5)
e <- rnorm(100,0,1)
y <- 2*x+3*z+e
df <- data.frame(x,z,e,y)

# Loading Zelig
require(Zelig)

# Model
m1.zelig <- zelig(y ~ x + z, model="ls", data=df)
summary(m1.zelig)

# Simulating z = 10
s1 <- setx(m1.zelig, z = 10)
simulation <- sim(m1.zelig, x = s1)
summary(simulation)
```

So `Zelig` keeps x at its mean (20.56), and simulates the quantity of interest with z = 10. In this case, y is approximately 71.

The same model using `arm`:

```
# Model
require(arm)
m1.arm <- bayesglm(y ~ x + z, data=df)
summary(m1.arm)
```

And using `rstanarm`:

```
# Model
require(rstanarm)
m1.stan <- stanlm(y ~ x + z, data=df)
print(m1.stan)
```

Is there any way to simulate z = 10 and x equals to its mean with the posterior distribution estimated by those two packages and get the expected value of y? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of bayesglm, you could do

```
sims <- arm::sim(m1.arm, n = 1000)
y_sim <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = sims@coef %*% t(as.matrix(s1)), sd = sims@sigma)
mean(y_sim)
```

For the (unreleased) rstanarm, it would be similar

```
sims <- as.matrix(m1.stan)
y_sim <- rnorm(n = nrow(sims), mean = sims[,1:(ncol(sims)-1)] %*% t(as.matrix(s1)), 
               sd = sims[,ncol(sims)])
mean(y_sim)
```

In general for Stan, you could pass s1 as a `row_vector` and utilize it in a generated quantities block of a .stan file like

```
generated quantities {
  real y_sim;
  y_sim <- normal_rng(s1 * beta, sigma);
}
```

in which case the posterior distribution of `y_sim` would appear when you `print` the posterior summary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @BenGoodrich! It works perfectly! Just two small questions: is there any of way to create `s1` without resorting to `Zelig`? Also, would the calculation be the same if I wanted to run, say, a logistic regression? Thanks again! :-)

Comment: `s1` is pretty much just `colMeans(model.matrix(m1.arm))` when all the predictors are continuous. In general, you can make `s1` any conformable vector. For a logistic regression model with bayesglm, you would do `rbinom(n = 1000, size = 1, prob = plogis(sims@coef %*% t(as.matrix(s1))))` All of these formulas are documented in the Zelig manual.